# Using XML to instantiate a class in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

XML File:

```
<MapDetails>
<MapTiles TileWidth="16" TileHeight="16">TestMap1Tiles</MapTiles>

<MapTileFile>TestMap1</MapTileFile>

<Enemy1Class>SkellMonsta</Enemy1Class>
```

Super simple. I want to use an xml file to define everything in the map. I have the xml file loaded properly in my GameState class. Everything traces out fine. (Using Flixel, btw).

```
add(map.loadMap(new TestMap1, TestMap1Tiles, mapXML.MapTiles.@TileWidth, mapXML.MapTiles.@TileHeight));
```

Could not use mapXML.MapTileFile to reference TestMap1.  I get this if I try:

```
Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
```

Same thing happens if I try to reference the SkellMonsta class like this:

```
enemies.add(mapXML.Enemy1Class = new mapXML.Enemy1Class(100, 40, hero));
```

I've tried using - as Enemy - but that doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to use a string value from your xml like it's a class.

You first need gain a reference to the actual class.  You can do this with [`flash.utils.getDefinitionByName`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName())

This method will take a string reference and return a Class reference.  Keep in mind though, that it wants a fully qualified name, so it should include any packages references.  So in other words,   `flash.display.Sprite` instead of `Sprite`.

So for your example, assuming your Enemy classes are top level, you could do:

```
var cls:Class = getDefinitionByName(getmapXML.Enemy1Class) as Class;

enemies.add(new cls(100, 40, hero));
```

Comment: Tried this and I keep getting Error #1065: Variable SkellaMonsta is not defined. I've tried to reference it every way that I know how. com.Actors.Enemies.SkellMonsta   ...    ../src/com/Actors/Enemies/SkellMonsta   ...   I even placed a test duplicate in the com folder(where this state class is located) and same thing.

Comment: Been playing with it here. If I do var cls:SkellMonsta = getDefinitionByName("com.Actors.Enemies." + mapXML.Enemy1Class) as SkellMonsta; by itself - no errors. If I add enemies.add(new cls(100, 40, hero)); I get: Call to a possible undefined method cls.

Comment: So I used the Enemy class path, which SkellMonsta extends. It's a level higher than SkellMonsta and has default graphics and all. It works! My generic enemy class shows, but skellmonsta is still an issue. seems like it just refuses to resolve the filepath to skellmonsta. What is my problem here? I do have them both imported. com.Actors.Enemies.SkellMonsta -- doesn't work. com.Actors.Enemy -- works

Comment: So, your `SkellMonsta` class is located in the `com` folder?  what does the first line say?   `package com {`?   If so, you'd do  `com.SkellMonsta` as the parameter to getDefinitionByName

Comment: com.Actors.Enemies.SkellMonsta   --- I even tried moving it into the level above: com.Actors.SkellMonsta  --- same folder as Enemy and same thing :(

Comment: Are you sure the class is being compiled into your swf?  That would seem to be the likely problem then.   Somewhere in your code, just put `SkellMonsta` as it's own line to make sure that class is compiled.

Comment: Or better yet, try this and see what the output is:   `trace(getQualifiedClassName(SkellMonsta))`;     If it doesn't error, then the result is what you'll want to pass to getDefinitionByName.  If it does error, then it means that class isn't actually compiled/available to your program

Comment: So I added private var skellmonsta:SkellMonsta; a the top of the MainState class. Voila. You sir are a genius +1. So I guess that I just need a reference variable for every enemy class in each level state to make it available to the state class. It'd be nice to just have a class that holds a reference to every enemy in the game. Would that be possible? I'll play with it. Thank you again!.............. Took all of 1 minute to answer myself. A reference class does work!

Comment: @PHaZerous You've run into one of the biggest gotchas using reflection in AS3.  The compiler tries to optimize your SWF by not including anything in your source tree that isn't referenced somehow from the root of your app.  Drove me nuts the first time I tried to do something similar in Flex.